# What is the proper way to pass multiple variables to MIMEText

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime, smtplib

I am trying to pass some variables to MIMEText then send those variables as a body in a plain text email.  Seems simple enough but no matter what I try I don't get the expected result.

Here is what I have:

```
import cgi
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()

cid = arguments.getvalue('cid')
cin = arguments.getvalue('cin')
dn = arguments.getvalue('dn')
sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y_%H:%M:%S')

msg = MIMEText(cid, cin, sttime)  #Here's the problem
msg['Subject'] = '911 was dialed'
sender = 'first_last@domain.com'
recipient = 'user@gmail.com'
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient
s.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
```

It sends the email but it only sends the first variable (cid) and it sends it as an attachment.  I would like all variables to be in the body of the email, not an attachment.

If I try to print the same thing that I'm passing to MIMEText it produces what I would expect:

```
print(cid, cin, sttime)
('9545551212', 'UserA', '04/12/2018_23:03:47')
```

If I simply feed a string of text to MIMEText it sends just fine.  What am I doing wrong with the variables?  I'm using python 2.7.14.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are you trying to send those variables as? That is, how do you expect the message body to look?

Comment: @cpburnz Just a string of plain text.  I though I accomplished that with the msg.as_string() in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MIMEText](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText) constructor accepts 3 arguments: `_text`, `_subtype`, and `_charset`.

- `_text` is the payload (message body).
- `_subtype` is the mimetype subtype. The default is `'plain'` will result in the mimetype `'text/plain'`.
- `_charset` is the character encoding of  the payload (`_text`). The default is `'us-ascii'` which means unicode cannot not be included. To support unicode, use `'UTF-8'`.

So with that in mind, what you want to do is construct the payload and pass that as the first argument (`_text`) to `MIMEText`. E.g.,

To create a payload formatted as:

```
cid: 9545551212
cin: UserA
sttime: 04/12/2018_23:03:47
```

You can do something similar to:

```
body = "cid: {}\ncin: {}\nsttime: {}".format(cid, cin, sttime)
msg = MIMEText(body)
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Worked perfectly, thank you so much.